# Flutter InputDecoration floatingLabelStyle font family

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to change font family of a TextField, but keep default input decoration style?

I set style for TextFormField, but it also changed font family of floating label. So I need to reset it to default value.

If I use floatingLabelStyle, it will also change color and animation while the field become in focus.

```
title: TextFormField(
  style: GoogleFonts.jetBrainsMono(),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Password',
  ),
),
```

Comment: `inputDecoration` has `labelStyle` and `floatingLabelStyle` you can use.

Comment: @PeterKoltai it will not change font of input text. The point is to change entered password font to specific family, but keep floating label with default style.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, Flutter uses the `style` set for `TextFormField` as a base style for the `inputDecoration` as well, check [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/style.html) and source code, but the point is:

> This text style is also used as the base style for the decoration.

It means that if you set some special properties in the `style` of `TextFormField`, you have to repeat and override them in `labelStyle` and `floatingLabelStyle` as well.

Check the following example:

```
TextFormField(
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 32),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Password',
    floatingLabelStyle:
        TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 8),
  ),
)
```

Now it you remove `fontSize` from label styles, you will see that these will still be affected by the `fontSize` defined in `style` (bigger, but not exactly the same size, because the engine makes some adjustments).

I hope you can adopt it to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I would like to have default style for floating label. I found that it is subtitle1 from current theme, but in default behavior it changes color when the field became in focus and out. I can not implement this behavior, becouse this inFocus member flag is for internal InputDecoration usage.

Comment: Give it a try, as far as I remember color change will work with the above code if you don't set color. If it does not, then I wish good luck to find your solution!

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me if replace fontSize with fontFamily. Looks not very smooth, but works. I'll add example in separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with code like this (thank you @Peter Koltai):

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: GoogleFonts.jetBrainsMono().fontFamily),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Password',
    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.fontFamily,
    ),
  ),
);
```